# MVC Controller data html.form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, forms

I have a view with a bunch of tabs holding editable information. Each tab has a "store" button, upon pressing this the data from this tab is pushed to a static instance of an intermediate object. 
Once finished editting the user clicks the "Apply Changes" button and the changes in the intermediate object get committed to the database.

The problem is when the user clicks the store button for some `Html.BeginForm("somemethod", "somecontroller"))` function because the page must return a view;
So I have to populate the fields with the intermediate object on loading the page as otherwise their non-committed changes wouldn't show up, but if the user refreshes the page  their non-committed changes are still being shown as the intermediate object isn't nullified when the page is refreshed. So I need a difference between the user refreshing the page my forms returning the view again.

So my question could have a few solutions,
How can I do a form in a similar manner that doesn't require to return any view, at the moment my form appears as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ModifyRemoteHost", "Management", FormMethod.Post, new { id="userForm"}))
        {
            @Html.TextBox("remoteHostName", null, new { placeholder = "Add User" })
            <input class="k-button" id="remoteHostAdd" name="sourceOperation" type="submit" value="Add" />
            <div id="status"></div>
        }
        <div id="hostsGrid"></div>
```

where `hostsGrid` is populated on the page loading.

or

Is there some way to tell how you arrived at this view so it can be known whether you want to discard the intermediate object,

or

redesign?

I'm new to MVC so apologies if what I'm doing is clueless.

Comment: Is my best bet removing the form and adding a Javascript url call function to the store button's onclick event?

Comment: Stay FAR away from static objects in any web application.  static objects are shared between all users logged in, you will write over each others objects.  Statics are fine for read-only data, but never for anything that is updated.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However it's for a configuration panel for a web service so the idea is it would be the same information for all users (although not all should be able to edit). Are statics still not advisable?

Comment: What if two people are editing it at the same time?  That's the problem with it.  Also, statics "disappear" when the app pool is recycled, which can happen at any time.

Comment: Ok, I guess it has to go so. How would you suggest I store this intermediate data instead so? In it's own database table?

Comment: That's the most reliable